# How to take screenshot in android/iOS mobile testing - C#?

Tags: c#, android, mobile, automation, screenshot

How can I take screenshots for different steps performing in execution of an automated test for android/iOS mobile in C# language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be [numerous suggestions on how to do this](https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin%20android%20take%20screenshot&oq=xamarin%20android%20take%20scre&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0.7202j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

This is one places code in `OnCreateView()`:

```
public static Android.Content.Context Context { get; private set; }

public override View OnCreateView(View parent, string name, Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
{
MainActivityContext = context;
return base.OnCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}`

Then, I wrote a service implemenatation in which I take a screen capture, by using the static Context of the MainActivity, like this :

`public class SnapshotService : ISnapshotService
{
public void Capture()
{
var screenshotPath = 
Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Pictures").AbsolutePath +
Java.IO.File.Separator + 
"screenshot.png";
var rootView = ((Android.App.Activity)MainActivity.Context).Window.DecorView.RootView;

    using (var screenshot = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(
            rootView.Width, 
            rootView.Height, 
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Config.Argb8888))
    {
        var canvas = new Android.Graphics.Canvas(screenshot);
        rootView.Draw(canvas);

        using (var screenshotOutputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(
                    screenshotPath, 
                    System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            screenshot.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, screenshotOutputStream);
            screenshotOutputStream.Flush();
            screenshotOutputStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

You can use this piece of code:

```
ScenarioContext.Current.Get<IApp>("Application").Screenshot(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
```